# LAN Game in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ip, lan

I have spent some time learning about socket programming in Java and have managed to make a couple of simple apps that utilize sockets. (instant messenger, tic-tac-toe, basic things) For my programs I used a client-server relationship with ServerSocket and Socket classes. So far I have been testing all my games on the same machine, meaning the client and the server both run on the same machine and the socket ip I am using is 127.0.0.1. Now I want to make a LAN game using the same logic. One computer will be the server and another will be the client.

The thing I wanted to ask, and pardon me if this is a stupid question, I am not really educated about networks and whatnot, but under what conditions can I establish a socket connection between two machines. What I mean is, I run my socket server on one computer and I want the socket on another computer to connect using the first computer's ip. Say, for example my ip is "192.1.1.4" I want to be able to connect to that computer. Is it possible to establish a connection like this between just any two computers in the world? I know "lan" stands for "local area network" but I am quite ignorant on it beyond that. Sorry it it is a dumb question and I can clarify it if someone needs me to.

Basically, what criteria must be met on two machines for me to be able to establish a socket connection between them using a Java program?

Comment: Thank you for the speedy responses everyone. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a TCP/IP connection between:

- Two machines in the same LAN (private IP)
- Two machines with public IP (internet)
- A machine in a LAN and a machine with public IP provided that the connection is openned from the LAN to the public IP

You can't open a direct TCP/IP connection to a machine inside a LAN from outside the LAN, unless the gateway is configured to redirect the connections to a specific port to that machine.

Comment: So if I have two machines with private IPs: `machine1 : 192.168.1.5` and `machine2 : 192.168.1.6`, would I need to open any ports, or could I just enter the ip into the socket and connect?

Comment: Hi @Cardinal System, you don't need to open ports in your router/gateway. You need to listen in one machine and then you can enter the ip/port in the other one to open a socket. Just make sure you don't have software firewalls interfering.

Answer (score 1):

On an internal network you do just what you said, client connects to server using server's ip address or hostname on the given port.

over the internet can be tricky because of firewalls and NAT.  For example, your computer's ip address on the home network is probably somewhere along the lines of "192.168.0.xxx" - but if you go to: http://www.whatismyipaddress.com you'll see that your internet facing ip address is completely different.  What you'll see is basically your router's IP address on the internet (WAN).

So basically, the server will have to setup port forwarding on their router for your game's port to his computer.  Then he will have to provide the clients with his internet facing ip address for connection.

Answer (score 0):

The main criterion for establishing a connection - ignoring a multitude of *possible* factors such as firewall configuration, etc. - is that the two machines are simply on the same network.  You may be aware that an IP address starting with 192.168.*.* always refers to a computer on a local network, which is the situation you are asking about, so if you have two computers connected on a local network (e.g. via a router), and you know the IP address of each machine, then it really is as simple as that - you connect in the same manner you have been using up until now.  In fact, the same applies on the internet - even if you have two machines set up on different sides of the world and you know their IP addresses (again, ignoring potentially more significant firewall issues), the process is exactly the same.  This is precisely the reason that the internet has proved so scalable, as the process of locating a machine with a particular IP address is handled by the lower layers of the network stack.

tl;dr: It's the same as what you are doing already, just with the appropriate IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a public IP address and you don't have to change anything about your own address, this is handled by your router that connects to the internet. What you do have to consider is your firewall settings. The ports you are using in your socket should be added to your 'allowed' list. Normally "established" traffic is allowed by default. This means that you need to allow your incoming ports @ serverside to go to your server.